# How can I prevent unintentional passing of arg in c-shell script that sources other c-shell script (linux)

Tags: csh

On linux, c-shell is default interpreter...

I source a c-shell script that I pass args to.  In that script, I source another c-shell script with no args.  But the args that I passed the parent script get passed to the child.

Q: Why is this ?

Q: How can I prevent passing the args to the child script

Simple example...

cat parent.csh

```
source ./child.csh
exit
```

cat child.csh

```
echo $arvv[*]
exit
```

What happens...

```
source ./parent.csh abc def
abc def
```

I would prefer NOT to pass "abc" and "def" to the child.

Comment: see https://superuser.com/a/618442/292141 as to why you see the argumeents in child and also for a possible solution. Btw it took me a whole lot of 5 seconds to find that answer...

Comment: It looks like the pointer you provided is talking about the difference between sourcing a script and running it in it's own shell.  In my case, I'm sourcing' both.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found my own answers.  (Please correct if wrong)

Nested "sourcing" (parent sourcing child in example above) behaves just like replacing the "source ./child.csh" with the content of child.csh (almost like an "include")  So if you example code was...

```
echo "This is the parents code"
source ./child.csh
echo "Parent exiting"
exit
```

and...

```
echo "This is the child code"
echo $argv[*]
echo "Child exiting"
exit
```

It would "really" look like...

```
echo "This is the parents code"
echo "This is the child code"
echo $argv[*]
echo "Child exiting"
exit    
echo "Parent exiting"
exit
```

The args passed into the parent are exposed to the child because it's in the same scope.  One problem with this explanation... Why doesn't it exit when it hits the "exit" in the substituted in child code ?

Anyway, If I call the child like this...

```
source child.csh ""
```

That seems to fix the problem.

Comment: sourcing is nearly like including, but not entirely. My mental modal of sourcing is one of "push the current script on a stack, now start the sourced script." Thus the shell knows that when it encounters exit it is in a sourced shell, and pops the original script off the stack + continues executing that.